# how to get integer variable name and its value from Expr* in clang

Tags: integer, clang

I have following code in an overridden method `VisitBinaryOperator()` for clang:

```
Expr* lhs = E->getLHS();  
Expr* rhs = E->getRHS();
```

I want to extract integer variable name and its value from expression `lhs` and `rhs`.

Say I have `x = 10;`, then I want to get identifier `x` from `lhs` and `10` from `rhs`. 
If I have  `x = x + 10;` then I want to get identifier `x` from `lhs` and `x + 10` as sub expression from `rhs`

Also for type I am getting this `: int identifier` when I dump `lhs` type

```
QualType type_lhs = lhs->getType();  
type_lhs->dump();
```

How this can be done for clang?

Answer (score 5):

Use `dyn_cast` to determine what kind of expression you have on the LHS:

```
if (DeclRefExpr *DRE = dyn_cast<DeclRefExpr>(lhs)) {
  // It's a reference to a declaration...
  if (VarDecl *VD = dyn_cast<VarDecl>(DRE->getDecl())) {
    // It's a reference to a variable (a local, function parameter, global, or static data member).
     std::cout << "LHS is " << VD->getQualifiedNameAsString() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

You'll need more complex code if you want to handle other expression forms on the LHS. If you want to deal with arbitrary code there, take a look at `RecursiveASTVisitor`.

To evaluate the value of the right-hand side (assuming it's something that Clang can evaluate, like `10`, not like `x + 10`), use one of `Expr`'s `Evaluate*` functions:

```
llvm::APSInt Result;
if (rhs->EvaluateAsInt(Result, ASTContext)) {
  std::cout << "RHS has value " << Result.toString(10) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: So Expr* lhs = E->getlhs() , where E is a BinaryOpeartor Pointer , I tried with this one but the control is not going inside the if condition.

Comment: Will it not work for a array variables if they are in lhs side?

Comment: @amithks Use `E->dump()` to find the type of the AST node. Clang has lots of implicit nodes that are created to represent the semantics of the program, and you will need to deal with that. If you just want to look at the program syntax, `E->IgnoreImplicit()` will skip a lot of implicit AST nodes. And `E->IgnoreParenImpCasts()` will skip even more, including grouping parentheses and similar no-op syntax.

Comment: I have almost similar issue @Richard. where I can't retrieve the IL value of a `ParmVarDecl` defined as an argument to a function and then initialized inside the function. then it was used as a parameter to the loop bound function. `RHS->getArg(0)` maches the VarDecl, but `VD->getInit->IgnoreParenImpCasts()` returns a SegFault (pointer to Null). Full question is here and thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64050621/matching-the-argument-passed-to-a-function-in-a-forstmts-cond-using-clang-ast-v