# Retrieve LHS/RHS value of operator

Tags: ios, objective-c, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, llvm-clang

I'm looking to do something similar to this [how to get integer variable name and its value from Expr* in clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189848/how-to-get-integer-variable-name-and-its-value-from-expr-in-clang) using the RecursiveASTVisitor

The goal is to first retrieve all assignment operations then perform my own checks on them, to do taint analysis.

I've overridden the VisitBinaryOperator as such

```
bool VisitBinaryOperator (BinaryOperator *bOp) {
  if ( !bOP->isAssignmentOp() ) {
    return true;
  }

  Expr *LHSexpr = bOp->getLHS();
  Expr *RHSexpr = bOp->getRHS();

  LHSexpr->dump();
  RHSexpr->dump();
}
```

This RecursiveASTVisitor is being run on Objective C codes, so I do not know what the LHS or RHS type will evaluate to (could even be a function on the RHS?)

Would it be possible to get the text representation of what is on the LHS/RHS out from clang in order to perform regex expression on them??

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I found something similar that works for this particular case.

Solution:

```
bool VisitBinaryOperator (BinaryOperator *bOp) {
  if ( !bOP->isAssignmentOp() ) {
    return true;
  }

  Expr *LHSexpr = bOp->getLHS();
  Expr *RHSexpr = bOp->getRHS();

  std::string LHS_string = convertExpressionToString(LHSexpr);
  std::string RHS_string = convertExpressionToString(RHSexpr);

  return true;
}

std::string convertExpressionToString(Expr *E) {
  SourceManager &SM = Context->getSourceManager();
  clang::LangOptions lopt;

  SourceLocation startLoc = E->getLocStart();
  SourceLocation _endLoc = E->getLocEnd();
  SourceLocation endLoc = clang::Lexer::getLocForEndOfToken(_endLoc, 0, SM, lopt);

  return std::string(SM.getCharacterData(startLoc), SM.getCharacterData(endLoc) - SM.getCharacterData(startLoc));
}
```

Only thing I'm not very sure about is why _endLoc is required to compute endLoc and how is the Lexer actually working.

**EDIT:**
Link to the post I found help [Getting the source behind clang's AST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11083066/getting-the-source-behind-clangs-ast)